# Silverlight: How do i assign a usercontrol's property value to a textbox?

Tags: silverlight, properties, user-controls, textbox, expression-blend

I have a user control which i have added to an outer form in silverlight. The user control has a textbox called txtRoleTitle, i have declared a property in the usercontrol's class called lableName and assigned txtRoleTitle.text to labelName as shown in the code below bellow, 
in the silverlight property panel, under the miscellaneous menu, i have set labelName to "Landlord", then added another one of this user control to the outerform and set its labelName to Tenant. But this does not seem to work when i run the silverlight dialogue. The value of the labelName does not appear in the textbox during design and run time.

Here is my code below. thanks

```
public partial class UserRoleDetails : UserControl
{
    public string labelName { get; set; }

    public UserRoleDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.txtRoleTitle.Text = labelName;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at dependancy property solution. Although while this may work if implemented properly, for what i am trying to do, this is an overkill solution. So i have a simple solution that works now, see code below:

```
public partial class UserRoleDetails : UserControl
{
    public string labelName
    {
        get {return this.txtRoleTitle.Text;}
        set {this.txtRoleTitle.Text = value;}
    }

    public UserRoleDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of txtRoleTitle.Text in your constructor, at the point of the assignment the labelName property will not have a value.

I think you need to look at making your labelName a dependency property and binding your txtRoleTitle control in the user control's xaml. Take a look at this example : http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/dependency-properties-in-user-control.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Secondly, you should make labelName property as notify property.

Thirdly, you should bind text property of txtRoleTitle to your notify property.

Alright, you are done.

Sample: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightcontrols/thread/052a2b67-20fc-4f6a-84db-07c85ceb3303/